# Terraform domain validation of AWS ACM certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, certificate

Using terraform to manage an ALB with HTTPS listener, the following code creates a new domain-validated ACM certificate in a Route53 DNS zone. Not sure if relevant, but note that it is a SAN cert with both primary domain and alternatives block. I maybe should also point out that this cert is for the default listener rather than an add-on `aws_lb_listener_certificate`.

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "ecs_cert" {
  domain_name = "${var.component}.${data.aws_route53_zone.root.name}"
  subject_alternative_names = [
    "${var.component}.${data.aws_route53_zone.root.name}"
  ]
  validation_method = "DNS"
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "ecs_cert_validation" {
  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.ecs_cert.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records : record.fqdn]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "ecs_cert_validation_records" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.root.zone_id
  allow_overwrite = true
  ttl = "60"
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.ecs_cert.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name = dvo.resource_record_name
      type = dvo.resource_record_type
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
    }
  }
  name = each.value.name
  type = each.value.type
  records = [ each.value.record ]
}
```

It works fine on a single-use Apply/Destroy cycle. Yet on a re-Apply to refresh an existing configuration, terraform marks the cert, the validation, and the validation DNS records as needing forced replacement, but the process eventually fails:

```
aws_acm_certificate_validation.ecs_cert_validation: Destroying... [id=2022-08-30 04:21:21.028 +0000 UTC]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.ecs_cert_validation: Destruction complete after 0s
aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records["host.domain"]: Destroying... [id=ZE85JJFU1M837__2661adc7d19531019d01facbc614f108.host.domain._CNAME]
aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records["host.domain"]: Still destroying... [id=ZE85JJFU1M837__2661adc7d19531019d01facb...4b-host.domain._CNAME, 10s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records["host.domain"]: Still destroying... [id=ZE85JJFU1M837__2661adc7d19531019d01facb...4b-host.domain._CNAME, 20s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records["host.domain"]: Still destroying... [id=ZE85JJFU1M837__2661adc7d19531019d01facb...4b-host.domain._CNAME, 30s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records["host.domain"]: Still destroying... [id=ZE85JJFU1M837__2661adc7d19531019d01facb...4b-host.domain._CNAME, 40s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records["host.domain"]: Destruction complete after 43s
aws_acm_certificate.ecs_cert: Creating...
aws_acm_certificate.ecs_cert: Creation complete after 5s [id=arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:account:certificate/8f5259e7-f1d4-47d3-b114-bb9fe341fcf0]
aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records["host.domain"]: Creating...
aws_lb_listener.listener_443: Modifying... [id=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:account:listener/app/service/51f1961f20605d59/3395894187b246f6]
aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records["host.domain"]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records["host.domain"]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records["host.domain"]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records["host.domain"]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.ecs_cert_validation_records["host.domain"]: Creation complete after 45s [id=ZE85JJFU1M837__2661adc7d19531019d01facbc614f108.host.domain._CNAME]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.ecs_cert_validation: Creating...
aws_acm_certificate_validation.ecs_cert_validation: Creation complete after 0s [id=2022-08-30 05:18:43.429 +0000 UTC]
╷
│ Error: error modifying ELBv2 Listener (arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:account:listener/app/service/51f1961f20605d59/3395894187b246f6): UnsupportedCertificate: The certificate 'arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:account:certificate/8f5259e7-f1d4-47d3-b114-bb9fe341fcf0' must have a fully-qualified domain name, a supported signature, and a supported key size.
│       status code: 400, request id: f45e0779-51a2-4e0f-ac12-b6ee04609810
│
│   with aws_lb_listener.listener_443,
│   on cluster.tf line 397, in resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener_443":
│  397: resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener_443" {
│
╵
```

I saw somewhere that this signature/keySize error is misleading and actually is indicative of the certificate not completing the DNS domain validation in time? Even though it says it finished?? I'd like to make it succeed on a re-Apply, because having to constantly Destroy+Apply is getting tedious...

```
Terraform v1.2.4
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.75.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0
```

Comment: Are ypu trying to do this in `us-east-1` or another region?

Comment: The output above shows us-east-1 for both the certificate and the 443 listener to which it should be attached, and I can confirm the terraform is running (eg the provider) in us-east-1 as well.